# I want to help data fetching query in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql-5.6, query

I'm fetching data from mysql.

But, query is so complex.

My case is like

Table schema

```
CREATE TABLE `mt_department` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '[ID]',
  `mt_company_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '[companyID]',
  `reference_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '[parentLayerID]',
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT '[name]',
  `layer` enum('1','2','3','4') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '[layer]',
  `registered_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_mt_department_mt_company_idx` (`mt_company_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_mt_department_mt_company` FOREIGN KEY (`mt_company_id`) REFERENCES `mt_company` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Row list

```
+----+---------------+--------------+----------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
| id | mt_company_id | reference_id | name     | layer | registered_at       | updated_at          | deleted_at |
+----+---------------+--------------+----------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
|  1 |             6 |            0 | Layer1-1 | 1     | 2018-07-27 14:45:49 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
|  2 |             6 |            0 | Layer1-2 | 1     | 2018-07-27 14:45:52 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
|  3 |             6 |            0 | Layer1-3 | 1     | 2018-07-27 14:45:55 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
|  4 |             6 |            0 | Layer1-4 | 1     | 2018-07-27 14:45:57 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
|  5 |             6 |            0 | Layer1-5 | 1     | 2018-07-27 14:46:05 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
|  6 |             6 |            3 | Layer2-1 | 2     | 2018-07-27 14:46:21 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
|  7 |             6 |            3 | Layer2-2 | 2     | 2018-07-27 14:46:26 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
|  8 |             6 |            1 | Layer2-1 | 2     | 2018-07-27 14:46:49 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
|  9 |             6 |            0 | Layer1-6 | 1     | 2018-07-27 14:47:01 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
| 10 |             6 |            7 | Layer3-1 | 3     | 2018-07-27 14:47:15 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
| 11 |             6 |           10 | Layer4-1 | 4     | 2018-07-27 14:47:27 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
+----+---------------+--------------+----------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
```

Let me explain data structure!

Layer can have 1 ~ 4. `reference_id` is 0 for layer 1.

`reference_id` of layer 2 row must has `id` of specific layer 1.

So, Now i want to fetch result like this

```
+----+---------------+--------------+----------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
| id | mt_company_id | reference_id | name     | layer | registered_at       | updated_at          | deleted_at |
+----+---------------+--------------+----------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
|  1 |             6 |            0 | Layer1-1 | 1     | 2018-07-27 14:45:49 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
|  8 |             6 |            1 | Layer2-1 | 2     | 2018-07-27 14:46:49 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
|  2 |             6 |            0 | Layer1-2 | 1     | 2018-07-27 14:45:52 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
|  3 |             6 |            0 | Layer1-3 | 1     | 2018-07-27 14:45:55 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
|  6 |             6 |            3 | Layer2-1 | 2     | 2018-07-27 14:46:21 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
|  7 |             6 |            3 | Layer2-2 | 2     | 2018-07-27 14:46:26 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
| 10 |             6 |            7 | Layer3-1 | 3     | 2018-07-27 14:47:15 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
| 11 |             6 |           10 | Layer4-1 | 4     | 2018-07-27 14:47:27 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
|  4 |             6 |            0 | Layer1-4 | 1     | 2018-07-27 14:45:57 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
|  5 |             6 |            0 | Layer1-5 | 1     | 2018-07-27 14:46:05 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
|  9 |             6 |            0 | Layer1-6 | 1     | 2018-07-27 14:47:01 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL       |
+----+---------------+--------------+----------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
```

If you have other idea Please tell me.

Thank you

Comment: It seems you need to sort data only, is it? If so, remove all fields from example data which do not depends on the result, and thoroughly explain why records are sorted in this order. Now it looks like a tree structure sorting, is it?

Comment: @Akina No. Not sort data only. Layer range is 1~4. 1 is parent. 2 is first child. 3 is second child. 4 is third child. parent can have many 2 child. 2 child can have many 3 child.

Comment: *1 is parent* I see, `reference_id = 0` shows it. *2 is first child. 3 is second child. 4 is third child. parent can have many 2 child. 2 child can have many 3 child.* And? It's a common tree structure, the only difference is that many trees (each starting with its own Layer-1 node) are stored in one table. As I see you output the firts tree (in scanning by depth order), then second one and so on... If not - explain thoroughly.

Comment: @Akina Sorry. My english is not good. Now Your understanding is same my case!

Comment: How many records do you need to sort? thousands? millions? billions? If first, you may create stored procedure which will obtain full path for each node (with zero-justified IDs) and sort records by it. If you have a bigdata I'd recommend you to change the structure to some tree-oriented one.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for your advice. I expect millions records. Do you have an idea to change the structure?

Comment: The sorting you need is the only task which processes the data as an hierarchical one? if so, additional fully qualified pathname (materialized path) field is enough (for 4 levels and, for example, 8-digit max ID it is to be VARCHAR(32)). But if the nodes may move from one tree to another (with their childs) or some another operations must be performed it's better to think for a special structure (nested set, for example).